# MVVM: How do I only read a property into a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have a little simple problem but I kind of can't solve it.
I am programming a Windows 8.1 App using C# and XAML as well as the MVVM-Light toolkit.

The thing I want to do is get a HubSections Height inside a ViewModel to be able to do some calculations with it.

How can I do that?

I've tried several bindings but everytime I bind the Height property of the HubSections to some property behind it gets set to zero.

I am sorry this seems to be such a simple question..

Thank you very much so far!

EDIT (further information):

Situation: I have a Hub-Section and within that a GridView. The height of the items inside the GridView should be calculated in runtime so that they always all fit the screen.

HubSection Height property:

```
<HubSection x:Name="SceduleSection"  [...]
            Height="{Binding Main.HubSectionsHeight, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

The GridView binds to:

```
<GridView [...] Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SceduleSection, Mode=OneWay}" [...]/>
```

I was hoping to be able to have the Height Property of the following Property inside the ViewModel:

```
public const string HubSectionsHeightPropertyName = "HubSectionsHeight";

private double _HubSectionsHeight;  

public double HubSectionsHeight
{
    get
    {
        return _HubSectionsHeight;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_HubSectionsHeight == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        RaisePropertyChanging(HubSectionsHeightPropertyName);
        _HubSectionsHeight = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(HubSectionsHeightPropertyName);
    }
}
```

But the value gets set to 0.

Edit 2 (Solution using triggers; Casting issue)

I've implemented the idea of McGarnagle and came up with the following:

Trigger:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
        <Core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                               MethodName="UpdateSize" />
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The method "UpdateSize":

```
public void UpdateSize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    HubSectionsHeight = ((HubSection)sender).Height;
}
```

Explaination:

I want to get the Height of the HubSection when the page is loaded for being able to play around with it. That is why I modified the "Loaded" event.

My problem is now that the "sender" in the "UpdatedSize" method does not contain the actual sender. Instead of that it contains an instance of the MainViewModel - why is that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your XAML that shows the binding, and the property definition from your viewmodel (these at the very least, anyway).

Comment: To be sure I understand: you're trying to send a height from the view/XAML, *to the view-model* ... right?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to achieve

Comment: tried Height="{Binding Main.HubSectionsHeight, Mode=TwoWay Source={StaticResource Locator}}" ?

Comment: Yes I apparently tried that already... :/

Comment: Wait ... this is kind of a weird approach.  Normally a panel like `HubSection` is responsible for the layout of its children.  Are you saying the `GridView` is the child of `HubSection`, but that it overflows vertically?  Or that it doesn't fill up all the space?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see your comment. The GridView does not fill up the whole space inside the HubSection but wait - you are right this is weird. I should try to get the height of the second Grid.Row inside that HubSection! I will try that - but I guess my problem above will still exist though.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [Blend SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726403%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) for this kind of thing in the past (very useful).  Use an `EventTrigger` combined with a [`CallMethodAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.callmethodaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx):

```
<HubSection 
     xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
     xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
...>
    <i:Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
           <ei:CallMethodAction 
               TargetObject="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
               MethodName="UpdateSize" />
       </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Triggers>
</HubSection>
```

Then the view model receives the event, which you can use to update the property:

```
public void UpdateSize(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs args)
{
    HubSectionsHeight = args.NewSize.Height;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried that now and it seems to be the right track I am on. All I have now is a cast problem. I will explain the issue in my main post above.